# Select SQL statement from multiple database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, vb.net, visual-studio

My question has 2 parts, and i am unsure if it is my query which is causing the error or data adapter.

Part 1. I have a mySQL query which works fine on SQLyog, the query involves selection from tables existing in different databases. And both databases has been set to have the same accecss rights for the user account used at the connection string.

Below will be my query.

```
SELECT `portaldb`.`users`.`full_name` AS 'Name of User'
    ,`Systemrevamp`.`System_countries`.`CountryName` AS 'Quoted For'
    ,`Systemrevamp`.`uniquequote`.`UniqueQuote` AS 'System Quote ID'
    , IF (
        LEFT(`Systemrevamp`.`uniquequote`.`username`, 1) = ' '
        ,'Web Access'
        ,'Bulk Upload'
        ) AS 'Type'
    ,DATE_FORMAT(`Systemrevamp`.`uniquequote`.`insertedon`, '%d-%b-%Y') AS 'Quoted On' 
FROM `portaldb`.`users` 
INNER JOIN `Systemrevamp`.`uniquequote` ON TRIM(`Systemrevamp`.`uniquequote`.`UserName`) = `portaldb`.`users`.`usrname` 
INNER JOIN `Systemrevamp`.`System_countries` ON `Systemrevamp`.`System_countries`.`Code` = `Systemrevamp`.`uniquequote`.`CountryCode` 
INNER JOIN `portaldb`.`permission_details` ON `portaldb`.`permission_details`.`user_ID` = `portaldb`.`users`.`user_ID` 
WHERE `portaldb`.`permission_details`.`group_ID` = '5'
    AND `Systemrevamp`.`uniquequote`.`insertedon` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
ORDER BY `portaldb`.`users`.`full_name` ASC,`Systemrevamp`.`uniquequote`.`insertedon` ASC
```

Visual studio keeps telling me there is syntax error and to check the version of SQL, but I am able to retrieve at the database.

Part 2. Below is a snippet of my code. My question for this part is, if the above query is used, what source table should I put for the data adapter to fill at 'XXX'?

```
myDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnection)
allUserDataset = New DataSet()

myDataAdapter.Fill(allUserDataset, "XXX")

gvAllQuotes.DataSource = allUserDataset
gvAllQuotes.DataBind()
```

Please let me know if more information is needed. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what SQLyog is but if your query is working can you make it a stored procedure. You can set the SelectCommand property of the adapter to a stored procedure. You can pass just the DataSet to the Fill method, no "XXX".

Comment: hi @Mary, yes it works now and definitely faster. thank you very much